# Query with colums based on distinct values in table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, dynamic

I have a table containing 3 colums. Location_ID, Product_ID and Qty:

```
LOCATION_ID |   PRODUCT_ID    |  QTY
--------------------------------
1                   1              1
2                   1              3
1                   3              5
2                   3              2
2                   4              2
1                   4              5
```

Everytime a product is taken in or out of a location, a row is being either created or updated in this table.

Is there possible to make a query that will add columns based on how many Location_ID's it's in the table?

I want the result to be something like this:

```
PRODUCT_ID | 1 | 2 |
--------------------
    1        1   3
    3        5   2
    4        5   2
```

And if there is added more LOCATION_ID's later, there will be a new colum named the location id (3) in the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use dynamic SQL for this

```sql
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
         CONCAT('SUM(CASE WHEN location_id = ', location_id,
                ' THEN qty END) `', location_id, '`'))
  INTO @sql
  FROM table1;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT product_id, ', @sql, ' 
                     FROM table1 
                    GROUP BY product_id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Output:

```
| PRODUCT_ID | 1 | 2 |
|------------|---|---|
|          1 | 1 | 3 |
|          3 | 5 | 2 |
|          4 | 5 | 2 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d1044/1)** demo

---

To simplify things on the client end you can always wrap it up into a stored procedure

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE products_by_location()
BEGIN
  SET @sql = NULL;

  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
           CONCAT('SUM(CASE WHEN location_id = ', location_id,
                  ' THEN qty END) `', location_id, '`'))
    INTO @sql
    FROM table1;

  SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT product_id, ', @sql, ' 
                       FROM table1 
                      GROUP BY product_id');

  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

And use it

```
CALL products_by_location();
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/798f1/1)** demo

Comment: Worked like when i created and called the stored procedure, exactly like i wanted!

But when i tried to run the dynamic sql directly in phpMyAdmin, i got the following error: #1243 - Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE.

Any idea?

Comment: Got it working by removing BEGIN,  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; and END